# Premature end of file error by XML parser while applying XSLT in Talend

Tags: xslt, talend

I have to convert an XML file in Talend Data Integrator using tXSLT. Here is the XSL Stylesheet code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- Configure $new-line below as your require for your text file format type. -->
<xsl:variable name="new-line" select="'&#x0A;'" /> 
<!-- An alternative configuration is '&#x0D;&#x0A;' --> 

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/rowData/rows"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rows">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(Plan,'|',Purpose,'|',Description,'|',Travel_Date,'|',Length_of_trip_days,'|',Air_Travel,'|',Total_Travel,'|',Total_Airfare,'|',Total_Hotel,'|',Total_Meals,'|',Total_Rental_Car)" />
  <xsl:value-of select="$new-line" />         
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I am getting a premature end of file error.  Any clue why.

Comment: Well how does the XML input look? Perhaps the error is reported by the XML parser the XSLT processor uses to try to parse the input to the stylesheet you have shown.

Comment: The input XML is something like this: <call name ...> <call method ...> <credentials../> <import data options .... /> <rowdata> <rows> <Plan> value </Plan> <Purpose> value </Purpose> so on and so forth for all the fields in a row and then the row is looping on. I need to convert it into a style like this: <header>Plan|Purpose|....</header>
 <rows>
 <row>value of col1| value of col2| ....</row>
 <row>value of col1| value of col2| ....</row> </rows>. So basically I need a | separated field values for all rows with no header coming in in every record.

Comment: @MartinHonnen do you need further details? still stuck at the same problem

Comment: Run the real XML you have through an XML parser to see whether it is well-formed, the error message you have shown suggests the input is not well-formed XML.

Comment: @MartinHonnen what XML parser are you suggesting. I have now changed platform, trying to parse and apply XSL through Python instead of on Talend. Have raised a new question - can you help with that. URL for the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998774/xml-format-change-using-xsl-file-in-a-python-code