# XML format change using XSL file in a Python code

Tags: python, xml, xslt

Have written a Python code to transform a XML file to a particular format using XSL stylesheet. 
Python code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree
def transform(xmlPath, xslPath):
  # read xsl file
  xslRoot = etree.fromstring(open(xslPath).read())
  transform = etree.XSLT(xslRoot)
  # read xml
  xmlRoot = etree.fromstring(open(xmlPath).read())
  # transform xml with xslt
  transRoot = transform(xmlRoot)
  # return transformation result
  return etree.tostring(transRoot)
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(transform('talendtest.xml', 'style2.xsl'))
```

style2.xsl content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:user="http://mycompany.com/mynamespace" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="/rowData/rows">
      <xsl:value-of select="Plan"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Purpose"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Description"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Travel_Date"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Length_of_trip_days"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Air_Travel"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Total_Travel"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Total_Airfare"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Total_Hotel"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Total_Meals"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="Total_Rental_Car"/>
      <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<call method="SOME" callerName="Travel_call">
  <credentials login="abc.com" password="XXXXX" instanceCode="YYYY"></credentials>
  <importDataOptions planOrActuals="Plan" allowParallel="false" moveBPtr="false" useMappings="true"></importDataOptions>
  <version name="API Test Version" isDefault="false"></version>
  <sheet name="Travel" isUserAssigned="false"></sheet>
  <rowData>
    <header>Plan|Purpose|Air Travel|Description|Travel Date|Length of Trip (Days)|Travel Costs &gt;|Total Travel|Total Airfare|Total Hotel|Total Meals|Total Rental Car</header>
    <rows>
      <Plan>Sales - North</Plan>
      <Purpose>Seminar/Conference</Purpose>
      <Description>Conf</Description>
      <Travel_Date>1/11/2015</Travel_Date>
      <Length_of_trip_days>3</Length_of_trip_days>
      <Air_travel>Yes - International</Air_travel>
      <Total_Travel>2455.0</Total_Travel>
      <Total_Airfare>1300.0</Total_Airfare>
      <Total_Hotel>750.0</Total_Hotel>
      <Total_Meals>255.0</Total_Meals>
      <Total_Rental_Car>150.0</Total_Rental_Car>
    </rows>
   </rowData>
</call>
```

Desired file content:

```
<call method="SOME" callerName="Travel_call">
  <credentials login="abc.com" password="XXXXX" instanceCode="YYYY"></credentials>
  <importDataOptions planOrActuals="Plan" allowParallel="false" moveBPtr="false" useMappings="true"></importDataOptions>
  <version name="API Test Version" isDefault="false"></version>
  <sheet name="Travel" isUserAssigned="false"></sheet>
  <rowData>
    <header>Plan|Purpose|Air Travel|Description|Travel Date|Length of Trip (Days)|Travel Costs|Total Travel|Total Airfare|Total Hotel|Total Meals|Total Rental Car</header>
    <rows>
        <row> Sales - North|Seminar/Conference|Conf|1/11/2015|3|Yes - International|2455.0|1300.0|750.0|255.0|150.0</row>
    </rows>
  </rowData>
</call>
```

However when I run the program ***python xslapply.py*** the output I receive is ***None***. There are no other details displayed. Please can someone help with if there is an issue with the XML file or the XSL styling applied which is not returning any actual result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSLT returns an empty string, because:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/rowData/rows">
```

does not select anything (because `rowData` is not the root element, and not the child of the current node). Try changing it to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="call/rowData/rows">
```

---

There are other problems. Why is your output method set to `text`, when your expected output is XML? And you're not doing anything to output the other elements besides `rowData`.

---

### Added:

To add a `row` for every record set (i.e `rows`), try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="rowData">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="header"/>
        <rows>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="rows"/>
        </rows>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="rows">
    <row>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Plan, '|', Purpose, '|', Description, '|', Travel_Date, '|', Length_of_trip_days, '|', Air_Travel, '|', Total_Travel, '|', Total_Airfare, '|', Total_Hotel, '|', Total_Meals, '|', Total_Rental_Car)" />
    </row>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**: if every `rows` has exactly the elements listed in the header, and in the same order, you could make the last template simply:

```
<xsl:template match="rows">
    <row>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have tried both the suggestions given by you, the answer still remains none, changed output method to xml and select = "call/rowData/rows". Please suggest how to output other elements besides rowData

Comment: No it's not - see: http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9k  There *may* be a problem with your Python code - I am afraid I know nothing about that.

Comment: Great thanks good to know that the XML format is coming as expected. Please suggest how to include the other elements and what changes need to be made in the XLS file for that, If you can point in the same link as above would be really useful. Thanks :)

Comment: @SwatiMishra No, I will not write your XSLT for you.

Comment: Well did not want the actual full answer, a hint could have helped - honestly Python, XML and XSL are all new for me and hence the question. But thanks anyways.

Comment: Hint: learn to use the *identity transform* template to copy the elements you want to keep as is; add other templates for the elements you want to modify.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I am able to see the correct result now here http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y9k/1  Although just a few modifications remain such as <row> ....... <\row> for every record set, do you suggest that is possible since it is not a part of the original XML document

Comment: @SwatiMishra See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the addition, I understand the styling part now. Also the python code bit is sorted.